# PyQt : accessing elements from outside the class

Tags: pyqt

First of all, I'd like to state that my question is very similar to this: [Accessing GUI elements from outside the GUI class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000361/accessing-gui-elements-from-outside-the-gui-class) . But since I am a newby in pyQt, I would like some more help.

I have the design.py file, exported from Qt Designer

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(150, 94)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 113, 27))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))
```

which is imported into the main class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import design

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_function)

    def button_function(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText('results') 

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So far, so good. I have created a window in which I press a pushButton and a message appears in the editLine.

This is what I want to achieve: I want the pushButton to trigger a function outside the class *(easy)*, and that function to deliver the message to the edilTLine *(hard)*. Something like this:

```
    def button_function(self):
        calculations()

def calculations():
    # somehow ...
    self.lineEdit.setText('results') 

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

```
    def button_function(self):
        calculations(self)

def calculations(obj):
    obj.lineEdit.setText('results')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. Than you very much.