# accessing UI elements from another class in python

Tags: python, pyqt

Example

function.py

```
class testClass(object):
    def functionA(self):
        #doSomething
        self.Qlabel.clear()
```

main.py

```
class mainClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent = #something):
        #initialize something

        super(mainClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Qlabel.clicked.connect(self.testFunc)


    def testFunc(self):

        import function as FT
        FT.testClass().functionA(self)
```

I tried connecting my PyQt `function.py` to `main.py`. It keeps giving me this TypeError: functionA() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).

If I take away the 'self' in so that it's `FT.testClass().functionA()`, then I get AttributeError: 'testClass' object has no attribute 'Qlabel'

I saw in [PyQt : accessing elements from outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709603/pyqt-accessing-elements-from-outside-the-class) that it works with just using `obj` but not with classes.

I would like to understand how to fix this and also why my previous method doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working. The problem was basically in `function.py`, I was using `self.Qlabel.clear()` instead of `object.Qlabel.clear()`,

This is the working code.

function.py

```
class testClass(object):
    def functionA(self, object):
        #doSomething
        object.Qlabel.clear()
```

main.py

```
class mainClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent = something):
        #initialize something
        super(mainClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Qlabel.clicked.connect(self.testFunc)


    def testFunc(self):
        import function as FT
        FT.testClass().functionA(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of functionA make one more Entry.
For e.g.

```
def functionA(self, mainClassObj):
    #doSomething
    self.Qlabel.clear()
```

Cause of the error is you're calling testclass function with one extra argument.Whereas you define it with one argument.

Note: You have to initiate Qlabel :

`def functionA(self, mainClassObj):
        #doSomething
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
        Qlabel().clear()`
This should work for you.

Comment: Also if you don't want to pass current class object then do following change 
        FT.testClass().functionA()

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and I'm getting another error: AttributeError  'testClass' object has no attribute 'Qlabel'.

Comment: means now you're able to call function. But Qlabel is not part of your testClass. Either make this part of testClass or import it. you better import it and remove "self." prefix. E.g. from PyQt.QtCore import *
from PyQt.QtGui import * and use Qlabel.clear()

Comment: This did not make it work either. It basically went back to Qlabel is not defined because it wasn't able to locate the ui's object name. I used a different object name instead of Qlabel in my original ui file.

Comment: Correct , if you're going to use PyQT's QLabel then you've to import same. If it's not working then please mention python and PyQt version you're using

Comment: In your above mention solution , now you made Qlabel as a member of mainClass. Hence now import the same in main class

Comment: yes. in my mainClass, it initialises that ui file. So, if the objectname is the default Qlabel instead of another name, then it should work just by importing QtCore into the file.

Comment: You also need to create object QLabel() then call it's method. See my edited answer.